# How to create an enumerated macro/newcommand

Tags: macros

What I'm trying to do is to create a \newcommand (not only theorems) and everytime I call that command it adds the chapter number and number of times that I call that command.

For instance, if I'm writting chapter #3 and I created a newcommand called \theorem, this is the output I'm expecting for the first time I call the command:

---

3.1 Theorem:

### Text

I know how to create the new command, I was googling this but didn't find anything relevant. This is the command I'm using:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
  \textbf{Theorem: #1}\\
   #2
}
```

Comment: For theorems specifically some of this functionality is provided by the `amsthm` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it much harder to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that works for general commands, not just theorems.

The idea is to define a [counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters) for your command, use `\numberwithin` to reset it every chapter, and then define your command to increment and show the counter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \numberwithin
\newcounter{eggs}
\numberwithin{eggs}{chapter}
\newcommand{\wine}[1]{
    \stepcounter{eggs}
    {\bfseries Theorem \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{eggs}}: #1
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Carrot}

\wine{Corn}

\wine{Ziti}
\chapter{Tomato}

\wine{Stew}

\end{document}
```

[image]